# Call jQuery.get after complete function

Tags: jquery

My code to parse website. Script call parser_init.php with param 'region'

```
$(function () {

    var  regions = new Array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,83,86,87,89,95);
    var max_region = 95;

    $('#parse-button').click(function () {

        NProgress.start();

        for (key in regions) {

            $.get('parser_init.php?region=' + regions[key], function(result) {

                $('#result').append ('parser_init.php?region=' + regions[key] + ' = получен; <br />');

                NProgress.set(regions[key]/max_region);

            });

        }

    });

});
```

It is essential that $.get carried after get result

Comment: do you want to run the script in a synchronized manner.. ie sent a request once the response comesback send the second request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {

    var regions = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 83, 86, 87, 89, 95);
    var max_region = 95;

    function getRegions(callback, idx) {
        idx = idx || 0;
        if (idx >= max_region) {
            return;
        }
        $.get('parser_init.php?region=' + regions[idx], function (result) {
            $('#result').append('parser_init.php?region=' + regions[idx] + ' = получен; <br />');
            NProgress.set(regions[idx] / max_region);
            getRegions(callback, idx + 1)
        });
    }

    $('#parse-button').click(function () {

        NProgress.start();

        getRegions($.noop)

    });

});
```